# Firefox laggy and getting me signed out from youtube everytime I restart it

Tags: 14.04, firefox, browser, firefox-extensions

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 bionic. I have installed Firefox from **synaptic**, **software centre** and also from **mozilla bundle**.
I have done **about:config** and whatever checks are given for **pipelining**, **networking**, **proxy** etc, done that.

It still lags in **youtube** playing, signing out at every restart from **youtube**, **scrolling** etc.

I suspected my issues are my **firefox plugins**, and I disabled all of them one by one, restarted firefox, but seeing no improvements.

**ad blocker** - removed no improvements

**ghostery** - removed no improvements

**duckduckgo privacy essenstials** - removed, no improvements

Not facing any of these issues with chrome. Its snappy and smooth.
Anyone facing same issue, or have any idea about it to solve.

```
Linux nikhil 5.3.0-40-generic #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 14:05:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

:~$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 73.0.1
```

Comment: What about cookies storage ?

Comment: @JerareYoshi yes that was the problem in getting me signed out every time. I did that and forgot, but scrolling is still a issue.

Comment: What video card do you have, and what version driver? What happens if you start Firefox in "safe mode"? Have you checked for proxies? Create another user account on your system... called "Testing", or whatever, log in there, and try FF and see if you get the same problem.

Comment: @mrigendra No... you don't become a tester for Mozilla. You come here, ask for help, and politely interact with users who try to assist. Tell me the EXACT Nvidia model #, and the driver version. And give me feedback on the other points from my prior comment.

Comment: @heynnema pardon for my previous comment. Trying to go away from google makes me frustrated at times. Thanks for the safe mode suggestion, I tried that and I see less stutter in scrolling now. Stutter is still there but good enough for me. My  gpu model is gtx 1660, driver version 435-tested.

Comment: You didn't say what happened when you tried FF from another account. At https://www.geforce.com/drivers they say the latest Nvidia driver for your card is 440.64.

Comment: @heynnema I have installed nvidia drivers from "software and updates > additional drivers", there are two versions showed 430, 435-tested. So I installed 435-tested. I will check 440.64 now from the website, and also check FF from another account, and will be back in 15 mins with results.

Comment: Try the other account first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105057/discussion-between-mrigendra-and-heynnema).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

We upgraded the Nvidia driver from 435 to 440.64 and the system is working fine now.